# Having an Issue screen recording on Android Studio, unreadable mp4

Tags: android-studio, logcat, screen-recording

I'm trying to screen record off devices using Android Studio through adb connect.

I'm successful in taking screenshots in logcat of my device, but when i'm trying to screen record, I only get unreadable mp4's.

I've tried recording in several different time frames, up to 1 minute and i'm still left with the same results regardless of the device used.

I've also tried to open the mp4 in VLC and Elmedia Player as well as adobe Premier Pro to see if i can edit at least preview the screen recording but same results.

I've also tried to mirror the device but my devices don't allow me to give permissions to mirror and ideally i would like to just be able to screen record any devices for my marketing materials.